# How to get selected index of toolstripbutton in c#

Tags: c#, toolstripmenu

I have a toolstrip control on a form and i programatically add buttons to the toolstrip control using the below code

```
            toolStrip1.Visible = true;
            ToolStripItem t = new ToolStripButton();
            t.Text = client.EndPoint.ToString();
            t.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;
            t.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("" + Application.StartupPath + "ps1_new.PNG");
            t.AutoSize = false;
            t.Height = 67;
            t.Width = 70;
            t.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            t.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            toolStrip1.Items.Add(t);
```

Now i m trying to get the index of the toolstrip button when i click on it 
note i can get the text of the clicked toolstripbutton using

```
e.ClickedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an index property on the toolstripitem click but you could do something like this

```
    private void ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ClickedItem.Tag)
    }
```

Where the Tag property is something you set as the index.